# SharePoin User File Relationship

Tags: c#, file, sharepoint, relationship

As I am working on SharePoint UserManagement, here I can find all the indvidual items like Users, Folders, Files, but the thing is I have sharred some files with some specific user from the SharePoint application manually,   I would like to make my automater to read this user to file relationship using c# code.

I am waiting for some good solutions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pls post what you have done yet. We do not do the whole work for you.

Comment: Hi all I got this solution,
 var OSI = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ObjectSharingInformation.GetListItemSharingInformation(cContext, docitem.Id, item.Id, false, false, false, false, true, false);
                    cContext.Load(OSI);
                    cContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    var Items = OSI.GetSharedWithUsers();
                    cContext.Load(Items);
                    cContext.ExecuteQuery();
this will help you to find the List items sharred with Users on permissions assigned

Comment: Blobonator, If u know anything post the solution, if u r not intrested please mind your business, dont interfer into others business

Comment: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)